# FileNotFoundException while getting data from Hbase in Aache Spark 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I have an application which reads data from Hbase and stages it on Apache Spark. I am using Apache Spark 2.4.4. When it runs for some days like after 20days, I get the following error. Can someone please suggest any solution for this?

```
ERROR Executor  - Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1417.0 (TID 8418)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/blockmgr-2f3bde8f-78b2-450b-b687-cf0a675d9731/34/shuffle_21_1_0.index.19149840-6163-445e-aa94-dd58fa38bfa3 (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:127)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: How are you running your jobs? Spark standalone? Yarn? Something else?

Comment: It might be related to `/tmp` directory. Something or someone could have deleted files in `/tmp` directory.